# Get products variation details

Tags: php, mysql

I will developing e-commerce website but need some help from you.

[image: Please find attached picture]

When I run query "SELECT * FROM `products_variations_option` WHERE `variations_id` IN (31,41) ORDER BY `product_variations_id` ASC" then I am gating this output but I need 1 and second row, Means I want only product_variations_id= 75 because 31 and 41 both value found in only product_variations_id=75

[image]

Comment: you should edit your post with a more suitable title ; currently "production variation details" does not mean anything for anyone who is not part of your project

Answer (score 1):

The below query may give you desired output

```
SELECT variations_id, product_variations_id 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM products_variations_option 
      WHERE variations_id IN (31,41) 
      ORDER BY product_variations_id ASC
) as t 
GROUP BY variations_id
```